# WAMP, .htaccess - get project content from sub domain

Tags: .htaccess, local

I'm trying to configure the .htaccess file, but I can't seem to figure it out.

What I'm trying to do:

Content is here:
C:\wamp\www\myproject

When I go here: 
http://myproject/ with a browser, it should display the content

The .htaccess file is here:
C:\wamp\www\

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^vivule/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ localhost/vivule/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

But this doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, but not with htaccess, but with creating a virtual host in system32 hosts file, read more here: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123740

The long RiggsFolly answer.

PS! This also solved the WAMP $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] problem for me.